# How to create a collection (or array) listing all parents and their children to pass to a view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I am quite new to Laravel. I know how I could do this but don't know if it is the best method. I have a system of items called "Flows". Each of them belong to a particular "FlowCategory". I would like to retrieve all the "FlowCategory" items and then their associated children ("flows") using the controller and pass that to the view.

The view I want will show a list of each Flow Category and it's associated flows.

I've set up Eloquent and the two items have a relationship. I have created a foreach loop in in the controller and have created an array manually but I'm insure if its correct.

```
       foreach ($cats as $cat) {
           $catid = $cat->id;
           $flows[$catid] = \App\FlowCategory::find($catid)->flows;
       }
```

Comment: If category belongs to a flow category, then you should take a look to Eloquent relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have already set up an eloquent relationship between the categories and the flows themselves. That is functioning well. But im unsure how to pass the data to the view with each category and its associated items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, maybe you to do something like that. But just to refresh the concept:

- Flows `belongsTo` a Flow Category
- Flow Category `hasMany` Flows.

Your models:

**FlowCategory:**

```
public function flows()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Flow', 'category_id');
}
```

**Flow**:

```
public function flowCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\FlowCategory');
}
```

That is, if you want to display in your view all Flow Categories, with their respective items, you can do like that:

**FooController.php**

```
public function bar() {
  // "with" is to avoid N+1 query problem
  $flowsCategories = FlowCategory::with('flows')->get();

  return view('yourview', compact('flowsCategories'));
}
```

And then, to display the `items` on your view, for each `category` you can do like that:

```
@foreach($flowsCategories as $flowCategory)
  @foreach($flowCategory->flows as $flow) 
     Flow: {{ $flow->name }} – Flow Category: {{ $flowCategory->name }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```